# shutdown -h now: FreeBSD server won't power down

Tags: freebsd, dell-poweredge, bios, shutdown

I'm not a sysadmin, but got a used dell poweredge r320 anyway. A problem I've been having with it is that after issuing the `shutdown -h now` command in FreeBSD the system goes through the init system shutdown sequence, then simply stays powered on after all processes are stopped. I haven't seen a computer do that since windows 95 when it would say "it is now safe to power down your computer". Is this a server specific quirk? I've been through every option I could find in the BIOS/UEFI. I'd really like to be able to power down the machine remotely.

[image: stuck here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [FreeBSD `man`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=shutdown&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html):

```
-h       The system is halted at the specified time.
-p       The system is halted and the power is turned off (hardware sup-
     port required) at the specified time.
```

I believe you need `shutdown -p now`.

Comment: Ugh. As a linux user this type of thing happens a lot. I'll try that when I get home and mark your answer as accepted if it works. Thanks.